# inline list of shuffled lists in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list that I want to shuffle multiple times and run operations on the shuffle.  How can I do that using list comprehension?

If `random.shuffle(x)` returned a shuffled copy of `x`, I could do something like this:

```
sum_of_list_operation_results = sum([operation_on_list(random.shuffle(list)) for i in range(20)])
```

But it just modifies the original copy of `x`.  Instead I have to do something like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
sum = 0
for i in range(20):
    random.shuffle(list)
    sum += operation_on_list(list)
```

What would be the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: If you don't like the in-place behavior of `shuffle`, you can use `random.sample(x, k=len(x))` as the [docs mention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Answer (score 0):

From [the `random.shuffle()` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> Shuffle the sequence x in place.
>
> ...
>
> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use `sample(x, k=len(x))` instead.

So, in this case just do that and you should be fine:

```
sum_of_list_operation_results = sum(
    [operation_on_list(random.sample(lst, k=len(lst))) for i in range(20)]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `random.sample()` and dont use `list` as var name

```
sum_of_list_operation_results = sum([operation_on_list(random.sample(mylist,k=len(mylist))) for i in range(20)])
```